# How to break the url into parts php

Tags: php, url

i want split url adress by / and choose the last one. For example, https://www.example.net/split/     https://www.example.net/admin/split/ i need to get the last action in url split, how i can do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [parse_url](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) might be of help, also [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: `strstr` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `explode`, if the url ends with `/`, remove it first, and get the last element of `explode`

```
$url = 'https://www.example.net/admin/split/';
if ($url && substr($url, -1) == '/') {
    $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
}
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$action = null;
if (count($parts) > 0) {
    $action = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
}
```